# How to include caption in pdf when export html table using bootstrap

Tags: bootstrapping

I'm trying to export html table data to pdf using bootstrap(shieldUI-all.min.js). I completed but i need the pdf format with caption ie) heading in the top of the table. I don't know how to do it.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
            $("#export_supplier_pdf").click(function () {
        // parse the HTML table element having an id=exportTable
        var dataSource = shield.DataSource.create({
            data: "#table_supplier_master",
            schema: {
                type: "table",
                fields: {
                    CODE:  { type: String },
                    Name: { type: String },
                    ContactPerson: { type: String },
                }
            }
        });

        // when parsing is done, export the data to PDF
        dataSource.read().then(function (data) {
            var pdf = new shield.exp.PDFDocument({
                author: "GBLS",
                created: new Date()
            });

            pdf.addPage("a4", "portrait");

            pdf.table(
                50,
                50,
                data,
                [
                    { field: "CODE", title: "CODE", width: 200 },
                    { field: "Name", title: "Name", width: 200 },
                     { field: "ContactPerson", title: "ContactPerson", width: 200 }
                ],
                {
                    margins: {
                        top: 50,
                        left: 50
                    }
                }
            );

            pdf.saveAs({
                fileName: "Supplier_master"
            });
        });
    });
        });
```

Or any other way to achieve the same thing???

Answer (score 2):

I believe at present there is no easy way to achieve this with the PDF options:
http://www.shieldui.com/documentation/grid/javascript/api/settings/exportOptions/pdf
Another option is to simply add the required data to the grid itself, so that it is exported to the PDF document.

Comment: yah I saw but I don't know how to use export options exactly and what are the js files required... If u can attach URL for the same with example.

Comment: You can use the following sample as a starting point:
http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-general/export-to-pdf
Also useful can be the getting started topic:
http://www.shieldui.com/documentation/grid/javascript/getting.started
which elaborates on the necessary resources to include.

Comment: I'm using php codeigniter. So is it possible to do it with the shieldUI...?

Comment: Just like you would include any client-side Widget.